# Updating a variable that has been casted with theano.tensor.cast()

Tags: python, theano

I am trying to update a theano variable in a function, simplified like this:

```
copy_func = theano.function(
    inputs=[idx],
    updates=[
        (a_variable, T.set_subtensor(a_variable[some_ptr], another_variable[idx]))
    ]
)
```

My problem is that I get the error

```
TypeError: ('update target must be a SharedVariable', Elemwise{Cast{int32}}.0)
```

The way I get this variable is through using the following (mostly copied from deeplearning.net tutorials) (`another_variable` is initialized similarly):

```
a_variable = theano.shared(np.asarray(data,
                               dtype=theano.config.floatX),
                 borrow=True)
print type(a_variable)
a_variable = T.cast(a_variable, 'int32')
print type(a_variable)
```

which prints

```
<class 'theano.tensor.sharedvar.TensorSharedVariable'>
<class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>
```

that is, the variable is no longer "shared", explaining the error.
This makes sense, as I guess the variable is now simply just a casted view of the original shared floats. But how can I update a variable that is casted efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this myself, and the answer was of course the obvious one.

Instead of overriding the `a_variable` variable with the casted version, I kept the uncasted version:

```
a_variable_casted = T.cast(a_variable, 'int32')
```

Updates are now done on `a_variable`, while `a_variable_casted` is used to perform the computations `a_variable` was used for earlier.

There might obviously be a more elegant way to do this, in which case I'd love to hear it!